# Deleting Files In A Directory Based On A Table

Tags: php, arrays

First of all, i would like to explain my condition right now.

I'm using PHP as my programming language.

I have a table named "Produk". It keeps every product name. Example value "TWC0001" in its id_produk column.

Every product have its own images, and stored in ./images/Produk/ directory.

the problem is, this project has been working about 1 years ago, and when the users delete a product, the product's images didn't deleted too. So, it still staying in ./images/Produk/ directory. It means, that file become a garbage right?

---

Case Example  :

in the "Produk" table, column "id_produk" i have 3 rows :

"TWC0001","TWC0002","TWC0003".

Of course each of those rows have its own images that stored in ./images/Produk/

Each of those files named :

"TWC0001.jpg", "TWC0002.jpg", "TWC0003.jpg"

---

Case : A user logged in and deleted row  "TWC0002", of course the "TWC0002.jpg" file still exist.

Problem : I want to delete all ".jpg" files that didn't listed in the "Produk" table anymore.

---

I've been doing this :

```
//listing all the ".jpg" files
$arrayfiles=scandir("../images/Produk/");

//getting all the product list
$sql="select * from produk";
$produk=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die("Error : ".mysql_error());

foreach($arrayfiles as $key=>$value)
{
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($produk,MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
    ///here is the part i've been confused of.
  }
}
```

---

PHP function to delete file is "unlink()";

Please anybody help me out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will produce an array with all the images that have no corresponding product record. I've left off the `unlink` command so you can do some reviewing process first.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Produk";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$existing_products = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  $existing_products[] = $row["id_produk"] . ".jpg";

$existing_images = array();
foreach(glob("../images/Produk/*.jpg") as $v) 
  $existing_images[] = str_replace("../images/Produk/", "", $v);

$images_to_delete = array_diff($existing_images, $existing_products);
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this answer really impressed me out. 
I love the "array_diff" function. Thanks so much, :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

`$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../images/Produk/'));`

`$regx = new RegexIterator(     $it, '/^.*\.jpg$/i', // only matched text will be returned
                RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH    );`

`foreach ($regx as $file) {`

`echo $file[0] , "\n";`

`unlink($file[0]);`

`}`

this will find all JPG files in the given folders and subfolders and will delete it

Comment: where should i put my database for matching the text?

You said "only matched text will be returned", where should i put the "text"?

anyway thanks so much for your effort helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following:

make directory listing of "Images" direcotry by

```
dir /b > filelist.txt (windows)
```

or

```
ls -1 > filelist.txt (linux)
```

You will have now list of existing files which should be imported to some temp table in mysql.

Now write simple SQL to select files without apropriate products (don't forget to append .JPG suffix).

with list of files to be deleted you can simply create file_get_contents and foreach loop unlink.

Reason why I recommend this is security.You can review what will be deleted.
Once you run script, there is no undo (just from backup).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(glob('../images/Produk/*.jpg') as $file) {
    if(is_file($file))
        @unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: please read the entire question first dude, :)
i wanted it matched with my database. Not checking if it is a file or not.